# Cannot get values for query parameters when using POST in Delphi REST Server

Tags: rest, delphi

I have written a REST server with an action `POSTCameras` to update. In the client i have te following

```
RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
RESTClient.BaseURL := EditERServiceUrl.Text;
RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
RESTRequest.Resource := 'GetUpdateCameras';
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('thislocn', '0000', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('cameras', '{"id":1,"name":"Camera 1"}', 
RESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

If I use `rmGET`, I can easily extract the parameters in the REST server using

```
ThisStore = Request.QueryFields.Values['thislocn'];
ThisCamera = Request.QueryFields.Values['camera'];
```

If I use `rmPOST`, the Query Fields are blank.

I'm not sure what I have to do to get the query parameters from the `TWebRequest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify what kind of server technology do you use, but I guess it's DataSnap (REST server).

In your REST client code you manually add parameters of kind `pkGETorPOST` to the request. This is BTW the default kind when adding a parameter via method [`AddItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameterList.AddItem), so you don't need to specify it at all and use an invariant with just 2 parameters `function AddItem(const AName, AValue: string): TRESTRequestParameter; overload;`.

[The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind) for `pkGETorPOST` clearly states

> **`pkGETorPOST`**: Sends the parameter as a URL parameter (for GET requests) or as a body parameter (for POST/PUT requests).

That means in case of `GET` request, the parameters are transferred in query string of the URL, while in case of `POST` request they're sent in the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded` string. To read such values from the request's body in server code you have to use property [`ContentFields`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest.ContentFields) instead.

```
ThisStore = Request.ContentFields.Values['thislocn'];
ThisCamera = Request.ContentFields.Values['camera'];
```

If you insist on sending parameters in URL even for `POST` requests then add them as `pkQUERY`.

> **`pkQUERY`**: Sends the Parameter explicitly as a URL parameter (for all requests), in contrast to `pkGETorPOST`, when parameter location depends on the request type.

Unfortunatelly `pkQUERY` wasn't available prior to [Delphi 10.3 Rio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What%27s_New#Improvements_for_REST).

Comment: Yes, I am using DataSnap and would only use the url for GET requests. Thank you for the prompt reply!